# how to put some value in to combobox dropdown list without adding it in to the store?

Tags: extjs4

my bbox config :

```
{
  xtype: 'combobox', 
  editable: false, 
  store: 'my.store', 
  displayField: 'name', 
  valueField: 'id', 
  name: 'rule', 
  fieldLabel: 'Rule', 
  allowBlank: true
}
```

my model:

```
Ext.define('rule', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  idProperty: 'id',
  fields: [
    {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
    name,
    {name: 'json', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'json2', type: 'string'}
  ]
});
```

my store:

```
Ext.define('Et.store.odinkod.Rules', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
pageSize: 50,

proxy: {
    headers: {'hash': 'hashnumber1'},
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'api/rule',
    reader: {type: 'json', root: 'data'},
    writer: {type: 'json', root: 'data'}
},
/*
listeners: {
    load: function() {

        if(count == 0){

           count++;
              var instance = Ext.create('Et.model.rule', {
              id: '',
              accountHash: '',
              name: 'Always',
              json: '',
              uiJson: '',
              comment: ''
          });   
        this.add(instance);
    }

    }
    },
*/
autoLoad: true,
autoSync: true,
model: 'rule'
});
```

so i want to see additional "name" field in the dpopbox without making new record

i can solve my problem if i do "add" method at the store. but thats bad way for me

Comment: Why is that a bad way? Could you not give the 'Always' value an id of something like '-1' and then respond to that selection in the handler for the combo?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the normal way to add the new item to the store. It will `sync` with the DB because of your configs `autoLoad: true, autoSync: true` to the store.

You still can achieve your goal by directly handle the Element of the dropbox, even with the DOM of the dropbox (try Component.getEl().dom). However it is just work-around and is not recommended because the store may fire errors when loading/syncing and/or you will get the data duplicated when the dropbox re-render itself after any actions cause store load.